# Where is this blue tile in the New York subway?

Tags: public-transport, new-york-city, identify-this

[image: Mostly blue tiles in a subway station interior]

About three years ago I took this picture inside a subway station somewhere in New York, either in Manhattan or Brooklyn. Now that I'm back in New York for a short while, I'd like to track down this place once more. Which station could I find this blue-tiled wall in?

Comment: @ZachLipton: Those appear to be aligned in neat rows, unlike OP's photo.

Comment: Would you happen to know the color line or the types of area you went during your stay?

Comment: Have you tried doing a Google image search searching for something like "nyc subway blue mosaic"? I'm seeing some possibilities.

Comment: I've checked out the image search but all of them seem to be fairly small sections; this was an entire wall (at the base of a stair, I think?) that was done this way.

Comment: For some reason I want to say you can find it at the 14th station on the ACE line (the blue line) but it is hard to confirm when there is 0 pictures of the platform or any other image relating to the one you posted.

Comment: We were in Manhattan almost exclusively except for one trip to Brooklyn for Roberta's; I thought this might be at the station by the Natural History Museum but I didn't see it there. We were staying around Gramercy and mainly went down to SoHo or up to Times Square and Central Park.

Answer (score 6):

My first inclination was to guess that it came from one of the station signs, as at [23rd St](https://macaulay.cuny.edu/eportfolios/eversleyarts13/2013/09/26/23rd-street-subway-station-art/), but the tiles in your photograph seem to be smaller and more irregular, as well as brighter, and so may have come from a larger mosaic.

As such, I don't have a definite answer for you, but will point you to the most comprehensive collection of NYC Subway art I could find, from unofficial/fan site [NYCSubway.org](https://www.nycsubway.org/). They currently have 295 works in their **[Subway Art Guide](https://www.nycsubway.org/perl/artwork)**.

Tile mosaics featuring large swathes of dark blue include *[Blooming](https://www.nycsubway.org/wiki/Artwork:_Blooming_(Elizabeth_Murray))* by Elizabeth Murray at Lexington Ave / 59th Street (4/5/6/N/R/W services), and *[Happy City](https://www.nycsubway.org/wiki/Artwork:_Happy_City_(Peter_Sis))* by Peter Sis at 86th Street Lexington (4/5/6 services), but again the pattern does not quite match. There are a few others with expanses of blue tile, like [at Court Street](https://www.nycsubway.org/wiki/Artwork:_Temple_Quad_Reliefs_(Frank_Olt)) or [at Eastern Parkway](https://www.nycsubway.org/wiki/Artwork:_Historic_New_York_City_Architectural_Elements_(Brooklyn_Museum_of_Art_Collections)), but you say you didn't spend any time in those parts of the city.

So the best I can offer is to look through station-by-station to see if anything jogs your memory. It's also possible that the photo you took is not technically of part of the station, but part of a pedestrian accessway from a building or other structure.

Comment: I recall this mosaic being within the station itself, not very far from the train I'd just gotten off of.